# calculate total angle between selected faces

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I have a framework for selecting holes in objects.
Right now it works by manually clicking inside the hole (with “by angle” option on), it then selects the inside of the hole.
I then delete the faces, select “open edge” then cap it.
This is what my script does now.

All of this works fine, but I do not want to click each hole separately.

To put it into perspective:
I’ve got 10 models (engineering models, hardsurface), each
model is at least 5000 separate parts, which I now have to go through
and remove the holes by using the above way of doing it.

So this is what I think might do the trick:

1) Select each face 1 by 1 with softselection.
2) each time check what the angles are in the selection.
3) if it’s a hole, then it’s a ~360 angle, I then know that this is
something I want to remove.

The part I need help with, is getting the total angle of the selected faces.

the rest of it is already done.

the case would be a simple box,with a cylinder through it, which you use boolean to create the hole in the box.

Answer (score 2):

this is a basic function I use in my scripts, facenormals are normalised vectors ( lenght = 1.0 and start in [0,0,0]) they point out of the face.

fn getAnglebetweentwoFaces face1 face2 =

```
(-- returns the angle between 2 facenormals

    theAngle = acos(dot face1 face2)

    --format"\tthe Angle: %\n" theAngle --uncomment this listener output if you want.

    return theAngle

)
```

Hope this will help you further